# terraform ebs_block_device vs aws_ebs_volume resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Could someone please point out the difference between using instance parameter:

> [ebs_block_device](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#ebs_block_device)

and using resource:

> [aws_ebs_volume](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html) + aws_volume_attachment

From terraform docs looks like the achieve the same result. 
As we're talking about infrastructure management I'd like to know the subtle differences in advance but can't find any.

I'd be grateful is someone would point the gotchas and use-cases for each.

Comment: The primary difference is that for the former, the EBS will be destroyed and created when the instance is destroyed and recreated, and for the latter the EBS will be detached and reattached when the instance is destroyed and recreated. There are also different arguments available for each resource with differing functionality, but those are illustrated in the documentation. Hopefully someone with complete knowledge can provide a complete answer though.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard I've found one difference that looks like internal TF bug in the blog post below: 
https://heap.io/blog/engineering/terraform-gotchas
(title: There’s more than one way to do it, so choose carefully!)

Hope to see someone share more on the diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, within AWS there isn't a difference with the volume that is created. The same options, features, and limitations apply to volumes created using the `BlockDeviceMapping` parameter of the [`RunInstances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) API and the [`CreateVolume`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateVolume.html) API. These are the APIs called by the Terraform AWS provider's [`aws_instance`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_instance.go#L607) and [`aws_ebs_volume`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_ebs_volume.go#L127) resources behind the scenes. It's a situation where [TMTOWTDI - There's more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

The intent (from the AWS standpoint) is that you may want to create an empty volume, attach it to instance, do something with it, detach it, take a snapshot, etc. It allows for better storage flexibility. This is derived from the concept of [storage virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization).

Comment: Thanks @Ben, 
Conceptually IMHO you're right but i afraid from TF point of view there are differences(one example can be found here: https://heap.io/blog/engineering/terraform-gotchas).